# Can i disable spellchecker popup but keep the red underline?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, text-input, spell-check

The red underline on misspelled words is excellent, but the popup is awful.

This is the popup I do not want:

[image: IMG:]

My keyboard app has a much better suggestion list, always. I think because it learns my typed words and handles two languages simultaneously, while the native android spell checker can't do either of those things. But the keyboard app cannot underline words.
[image]

The unwanted popup breaks my accessibility input (I use a physical keyboard), forcing me to always:

1. click/touch the misspelled word,
2. wait for popup to show up with useless suggestions,
3. press back button to close popup,
4. click the correct word on the keyboard suggestion bar.

Is there any way to only highlight misspelled words and not show any popup on touch/click?

Answer (score -1):

There ought to be a setting for the keyboard you are using.

I use "[Gboard - the Google Keyboard (Beta)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en_CA)", it's quite good. Multilingual typing, probably in your languages. Easy to use Emoji searching, .GIFs, Swipe, 'Google Translate' typing, and it has voice input too.

Settings -> General Management -> Language and Input, section "Input Correction" - set "Spelling Correction" to off. It still gives 'one line suggestions' but no 'pull down' like in your example.

Comment: i tried google keyboard, and I still got the suggestions disabled while disabling the menu. And it is the only keyboard i tested that have zero support for a physical keyboard, making things even worse :(

Comment: I don't have a physical keyboard but I can see in the settings that Gboard supports a physical keyboard. Here is a support page for SwiftKey: "[How to use SwiftKey with physical/external Bluetooth keyboards on Android](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201591341-How-to-use-SwiftKey-with-physical-external-Bluetooth-keyboards-on-Android)". I don't use SwiftKey but remember using it and not liking it for some reason. Whether that support page will assist with Gboard or be useful if you decide to try SwiftKey remains to be seen. Hopefully a more helpful answer will come soon.

Comment: Here's a [forum thread](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-pro-12-2/445464-possible-use-bluetooth-keyboard-spell-check.html) were some people report positive results with SwiftKey while others do not. Here's a thread were people say they've had [success with Gboard and a physical keyboard](https://support.google.com/nexus/forum/AAAANseOu18ZMf5T_-W3lY/?hl=en) except for Emojis - they suggested contacting Google Support to get assistance with that.